# Generic way to translate $ngBootbox messages with $translate service

Tags: angular-translate

I'm using [$ngBootbox](https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngBootbox) module to display alerts and confirm dialogs.
Also, I'm using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) module to translate my string resources.

I wanted a generic way to implement these translations shown in dialogs to avoid repetitive and dirty code as follows:

```
$scope.displayMsg = function(){
    $translate('message').then(function(translated_msg){
        $ngBootbox.alert(translated_msg);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to share this solution using $provide.decorator

```
app.config(function($provide){
    $provide.decorator('$ngBootbox', function($delegate, $translate, $q){
        return angular.extend($delegate, {
            alert: customMessageHandler($delegate.alert),
            confirm: customMessageHandler($delegate.confirm),
            prompt: customMessageHandler($delegate.prompt)
        });

        //Receives the delegated method from $ngBootbox
        function customMessageHandler(method){
            return function(message){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $translate(message).then(function(translated_message){
                    deferred.resolve(method(translated_message));
                }, function(){
                    deferred.resolve(method(message));
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
        }

    });
});
```

Example of use with $translate string resource:

```
$scope.displayMsg = function(){
    $ngBootbox.alert('my_string_resource');
}
```

Also I can use custom text:

```
$scope.displayMsg = function(){
    $ngBootbox.alert('My custom not_translated message!');
}
```